# The better way to use Jquery with Google maps API, change InfoWindow style

Tags: jquery, maps

I used to work with Jquery and Google maps API, and i've found some answers here, but i didn't found any workable examples. Please if you have one, or just give me a link.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the infowindow style - you might have to implement your own custom overlay such as here http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latlng-to-coord-control/latlng-to-coord-control.html or use Info Box from Google Utilities Library http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

Answer (score 0):

thi sone is very simple to use : http://gmap.nurtext.de/
check this out for more options : http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/03/10-jquery-plugins-for-easier-google-map-installation/